# C#: Any() vs Count() for an empty list

Tags: c#, .net

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189602/ternary-best-practice/) posted earlier got me thinking. Would `Any()` and `Count()` perform similarly when used on an empty list?

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0), both should go through the same steps of `GetEnumerator()/MoveNext()/Dispose()`.

I tested this out using quick program on LINQPad:

```
static void Main()
 {
    var list = new List<int>();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        list.Any();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed for Any()   : {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);


    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        list.Count();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed for Count(): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

And the general result seems to indicate that `Count()` is faster in this situation. Why is that?

I'm not sure if I got the benchmark right, I would appreciate any correction if not.

---

Edit: I understand that it would make more sense semantically. The first link I've posted in the question shows a situation where it does make sense to do use `Count()` directly since the value would be used, hence the question.

Comment: They would both be very fast but, if testing a `List` just use the `Count` property, rather than the `Count()` extension, that requires no enumeration.

Comment: What exactly did your benchmarks show? I'd expect that calling either of these just 10000 times would be so fast as to not be sensibly measurable.

Comment: The reason `Any` is better generally is because it only needs to find one thing in the enumeration, but count needs to find all of them. In your test the list is empty so obviously finding the first, and finding all doesnt make much difference

Comment: `note that the LINQ-to-Objects implementation of Count() does check for ICollection<T> (using .Count as an optimisation) - so if your underlying data-source is directly a list/collection, there won't be a huge difference` From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0

Comment: Relevant: A post I wrote a long time ago about understanding the differences of `Any` vs `Count`, when to use them (and more importantly, when *not* to use them): http://www.caspershouse.com/post/Anything-Counts.aspx

Comment: Actually you are already linking to the question which answers this. As also mentioned there, IMO it is much better to prefer whatever is semantically more accurate (unless you are on a CPU-bound critical path, but that's so rare).

Comment: @JonSkeet The values displayed were very small, but there is a consistent difference. Here's one output `Time elapsed for Any()   : 00:00:00.0004658` & `Time elapsed for Count(): 00:00:00.0001871`

Comment: `Count()` on a `ICollection<T>` will just use the `Count` property.

Comment: I added a warm up and changed it to 100000000 iterations. `Time elapsed for Any()   : 00:00:03.7086543`, `Time elapsed for Count(): 00:00:01.6072861
`

Comment: Does the LINQ method Count() on a list just use the Count property? In which case I wouldn't be surprised if it is quicker given that it is just referencing a property rather than interacting with the enumerator

Comment: While theoretically interesting, I'd suggest that this question has little value anyway: if you already know the list is empty, you don't need to call either method; if you don't know, you should prefer `Any` over `Count`.

Comment: Although it's an interesting question, performance is no key concern in this case; while showing business intend is. Therefore, Any() is the recommended approach.

Comment: @casperOne Your answer was valid? Why the deletion?

Comment: @mattytommo I didn't feel that it directly answered the question, it answered the general question that was referenced in the question this was incorrectly closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: I think you need to compare `Any()` with `Count() == 0` instead of just `Count()`... but would that make a difference for the performance results?

Comment: The question was why Count() was faster than Any() when it's normally the other way around.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Count()` method is optimized for `ICollection<T>` type, so the pattern `GetEnumerator()/MoveNext()/Dispose()` is not used.

```
list.Count();
```

Is translated to

```
((ICollection)list).Count;
```

Whereas the `Any()` has to build an enumerator.
So the `Count()` method is faster.

Here are average benchmarks for 4 different `IEnumerable` instances, across 100 million repetitions each. The `MyEmpty` looks like `IEnumerable<T> MyEmpty<T>() { yield break; }`:

| Function | Any() | Count() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new List() | 4.310 | 2.252 |
| Enumerable.Empty() | 3.623 | 6.975 |
| new int[0] | 3.960 | 7.036 |
| MyEmpty() | 5.631 | 7.194 |

As [casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190415/c-any-vs-count-for-an-empty-list/16191520#comment23157025_16191520) said in the comment, `Enumerable.Empty<int>() is ICollection<int>`, because it is an array, and arrays are not good with the `Count()` extension because [the cast to `ICollection<int>` is not trivial.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208951/array-count-much-more-slower-than-list-count)

Anyway, for a homemade empty `IEnumerable`, we can see what we expected, that `Count()` is slower than `Any()`, due to the overhead of testing if the `IEnumerable` is a `ICollection`.

Complete benchmark:

```
class Program
{
    public const long Iterations = (long)1e8;

    static void Main()
    {
        var results = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>>();
        results.Add("new List<int>()", Benchmark(new List<int>(), Iterations));
        results.Add("Enumerable.Empty<int>()", Benchmark(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), Iterations));
        results.Add("new int[0]", Benchmark(new int[0], Iterations));
        results.Add("MyEmpty<int>()", Benchmark(MyEmpty<int>(), Iterations));

        Console.WriteLine("Function".PadRight(30) + "Any()".PadRight(10) + "Count()");
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", result.Key.PadRight(30), Math.Round(result.Value.Item1.TotalSeconds, 3).ToString().PadRight(10), Math.Round(result.Value.Item2.TotalSeconds, 3));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Tuple<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> Benchmark(IEnumerable<int> source, long iterations)
    {
        var anyWatch = new Stopwatch();
        anyWatch.Start();
        for (long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) source.Any();
        anyWatch.Stop();

        var countWatch = new Stopwatch();
        countWatch.Start();
        for (long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) source.Count();
        countWatch.Stop();

        return new Tuple<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>(anyWatch.Elapsed, countWatch.Elapsed);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> MyEmpty<T>() { yield break; }
}
```

Comment: Using `Enumerable.Empty<int>()` shows that `Any()` is faster than `Count()`. Thanks!